# how to display html with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am aware that content can be displayed with css using `content`

```
.email-address:before {
   content: "Email address: ";
}
```

But what if I wanted to do something like this:

```
.email-address:before {
   content: "<strong class='my text'>Email address:</strong>";
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see what happens? it'd probably take LESS time to whip up a test case and run it through your browser than it did for you to type this up and wait for an answer.

Comment: nop, but you can do font-weight:bold; and any CSS like any regular inline box. border:solid; float; display:list-item, ... whatever you need

Comment: @ctwheels Why would you use JS for it?

Comment: @MarcB i have tried it before posting this question. I just posted this to make it clear what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

No, but.

What you can do is :

```
.email-address:before {
   content: "Email address: ";
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

and or :

```
.email-address:before, .my-text {
    /* Rules for my-text */ 
}
```

---

```
<edit>
```

If your idea was to retrieve some pieces of text you can use data-attributes.

```
<p class="email-address" data-name="myName" data-com="mydomain.com"></p>
```

and

```
.email-address:before {
   content: "Email address: "attr(data-name)'@'attr(data-com);
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jxELg)

Answer (score 0):

No. No DOM element will be altered. The content will be only referenced as text and not HTML.